# Does order of precedence with ENV variable changes which program to use?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, paths

**Question:**  Does order of precedence in the PATH influence Ubuntu to choose which program to use?

**More details:**
I use `.bashrc` for declaring private env PATH, I have installed MSP430-gcc from ubuntu repositories which stays in /usr/local/bin and I have compiled my own MSP430-gcc and placed it under `/opt/compilers/msp430-gcc-4.7.3`:

```
#msp430-gcc 4.7.3 in .bashrc
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/compilers/mspgcc-4.7.3/bin
#the corresponding echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/opt/tools/MSP430Flasher_1.3.0:/opt/compilers/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin:/opt/compilers/mspgcc-4.7.3/bin
```

When I try to ask Ubuntu which MSP430-gcc it uses? It used to answer: `/opt/compilers/mspgcc-4.7.3/bin`.

But now it is answering the following:

```
$which msp430-gcc
/usr/bin/msp430-gcc  #the default installation from Ubuntu repo
```

**Problem:**
I noticed the above setting was not working after an update. ( may or may not be caused by an update) I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and updated on date: 16 december 2014

**Fix:** 
I had to change the precedence of environment PATH by editing .bashrc and change the precedence and put my custom path before system's PATH as below

```
#msp430-gcc 4.7.3 in .bashrc
export PATH=/opt/compilers/mspgcc-4.7.3/bin:$PATH (note the difference in locating :$PATH)

#echo $PATH
/opt/compilers/mspgcc-4.7.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/opt/tools/MSP430Flasher_1.3.0:/opt/compilers/Sourcery_G++_Lite/bin
```

**The story behind:**
This problem has already been reported (PATH appears on first has highest precedence (left to right):

- http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/56360-path-unix.html
- http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=329

Answer (score 5):

For me, this is logical: the `$PATH` is searched from the beginning to the end and the first matching executable will be run.

See the following Q&A's on the same topic:

- [Order of files to be executed in linux and how to change it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13088800/2353900)
- [How to correctly add a path to PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26047)
- [How does unix search for executable files?](https://superuser.com/q/238987)

So, first found, first used!